# Zend Framework 2, Model Error

Tags: php, zend

Cree un projecto de ZF2 mediante composer y luego cree un modulo mediante el ZFTOOL llamado "Login".

El problema se presenta al agregarle un modelo, que no esta funcionando, aqui agrego las capturas del proyecto.

El error que me genera en el explorador es el siguiente:
"Class Login\Model\Entity\Modelo not Found in....."

Si quito el llamado al modelo se va el error.

De antemano les agradezco mucho por su ayuda.

Codigo del Controlador

```
<?php

  namespace Login\Controller;

  use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
  use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
  use Login\Model\Modelo;
  class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
  {



public function __construct(){

}

    public function indexAction()
    {
    $modelo = new Modelo();


     $result = new ViewModel();


    $result->setTerminal(true);

    return $result;
    }

    private function sesion(){


  }

}
```

Codigo del Modelo

```
<?php

namespace Login\Model;

class Modelo {

    function __construct(){

    }

}
```

[image: Model]

Comment: Esta escrita en Ingles, debería estar en StackOverflow

Comment: SO te da la opcion para poner tu codigo formateado, te recomiendo lo hagas asi ya que es demasiado incomodo para leerlo en capturas de pantalla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambio `use Login\Model\Modelo` a `use Login\Model\Entity\Modelo;` , creo que esto va a resolver, Es un error de `namespace`.

Se llama a namespace que no existe en el controller.

Espero su respuesta.